# Cambiar el color de las curvas parámetro-x y parámetro-y sobre un gráfico de superficie 3D con matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy generando una gráfica 3D en Python con `matplotlib` a partir de un array de numpy `u_` de dimensiones `(101,101)` que he generado con una simulación numérica. Esta es la gráfica que he conseguido:

[image: Gráfica de superficie]

Y este es el código que estoy usand:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_formats = ['svg']

eje_x = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 101)
eje_t = np.linspace(0, 3.0, 101)

x = eje_x
t = eje_t
X, T = np.meshgrid(x,t)

U = np.transpose(u_)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$t$')
ax.set_zlabel('$u(x,t)$')

ax.xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

ax.plot_surface(X, T, U)

ax.view_init(30, 135)
plt.show()
```

¿Sería posible cambiar el color de las curvas parámetro-x y parámetro-y sobre la superficie (las señaladas con una flecha roja en la imagen), así como su grosor?

**Edito.** He probado a superponer un gráfico tipo `plot_wireframe`,

```py
ax.plot_wireframe(X, T, U, alpha=1.0, linewidth=0.5, antialiased=True, color='k')
```

Y el resultado ha sido similar a lo que esperaba, aunque aparece un artefacto no deseado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes incluir en tu pregunta lo que has intentado hacer/utilizar para lograr lo que buscas?

Comment: Hola, acabo de añadir lo que he intentado hasta el momento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Para encontrar los argumentos correctos:

La gráfica [`plot_surface`](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) crea una [`Poly3DCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html), que se basa en [`PolyCollections`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html) (Te recomiendo visitar todos los links para entender mejor los argumentos de `plot_surface`)

Es decir, `plot_surface` puede recibir los argumentos `linewidth` y `edgecolors` para controlar el color y el ancho de las líneas.

Como no agregaste la matriz, cree un ejemplo sencillo de como utilizarlo basándolo en tu código

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_formats = ['svg']

eje_x = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 101)
eje_t = np.linspace(0, 3.0, 101)

x = eje_x
t = eje_t
X, T = np.meshgrid(x,t)

R = np.sqrt(X**2 + T**2)
u_ = np.sin(R)

#u_ = np.matrix(np.arange(10201).reshape((101,101)))

U = np.transpose(u_)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$t$')
ax.set_zlabel('$u(x,t)$')

ax.xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

ax.plot_surface(X, T, U, rstride=10, cstride=10, linewidth=0.5, edgecolors='r')

ax.view_init(30, 135)
plt.show()
```

Esto crea la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica]

Comment: Queda justo como necesitaba, gracias